# What is your favorite EQ?

Tags: favorite, plug-in, equalization

I know this question is pretty all encompassing and probably can't be answered, but:

What are your favorite EQs?

and:

Do you have different favorites for different applications?

Me, I like the Oxford EQ and the GML EQ plug-in for overall voice tonality.

I do have a couple DNs in my studio (hardware) but I personally hate setting back up a graphic EQ if I have to set up a mix again for changes - so I rarely use them, if ever. Pro Tools sessions are much faster because the EQ settings are saved and instantly recallable...

However, the stock EQ3 I find is the most effective at removing low-end from a mic pop.

But, that same EQ distorts sound effects like low-end rumble atmos if you try to high-pass it.

What are some of your favorite EQs and what is your go-to EQ plug-in for certain applications?

Comment: Oxford EQ are very good, but I like Waves :)

Answer (score 3):

Another good choice for me it's FabFilter Pro-Q. Very similar to Masterworks EQ in terms of visual feedback. I really like to "see" what's happening and having this visual aid, but I know I should never forget listening, at first!

[image]

Comment: man, that thing looks cool!

Comment: Looks like a Tron EQ.

Comment: Haha, that's true, I hadn't realized it before!

Comment: looks cool. i'll check it out. how heavy is on the cpu (i'm on PT)??

Comment: I use it on Digital Performer and Peak, so I don't know how it performs on PT. But with both DAW's, it's very light consuming. 

Comment: I like the Pro Q either... Fabfilter plug-ins sound great.. I love their delay Fabfilter Timeless 2

Answer (score 2):

My favorite is the Masterworks EQ included in MOTU Digital Performer 7. Very precise and frequency responsive. Love it's interface!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I mostly use Waves

Answer (score 1):

With only a Power Pack and Waves Diamond bundle to choose from I'm a little limited in my choice, but here's my take...

+1 on the EQ3 series. I find it quite useful, particularly for it's adjustable slope on HP/LP. Then fact that it maps exactly how you would expect it to on the D-Command is a big plus too.

While I'm not in love with it, I also use Waves' Q series quite often. It's narrow notch (Q=100) is like a scalpel that allows me to pull out just the frequency I'm looking for.

I'll also use the Ren EQ on narration for subtle voice coloration. As a result it's not unusual for the insert chain on a narration track to go: EQ3 1-band (for low-end rolloff) > Q6 (for surgery) > REQ 4 (for tonality) which then feeds the dynamics chain.

Comment: Ren EQ - I have to try that out. I don't have that pack but I've heard a lot of good things about it.

Comment: Waves Q is great for hums and background noise. +1 for REQ, my weapon of choice.

Answer (score 1):

I really wish Roger Nichols had not has his software falling out.  We still keep fireQ on our systems, but its starting to get left behind by the rest of the software.

FireQ has 2 awesome things about it that I wish the digirack plugin would incorporate:

- frequency response graph overlay
- matching

My workhorse is the digrack eq, but I use the filterbank stuff for the supersharp rolloffs.

Oxford eq is awesome, but we don't have it installed in all of the rooms so I usually stay away from in on projects that aren't one-offs and will never be revised.

Q1 is great for notching.

I'm very impressed with the eq inside of izotope Rx.

---

I never can get good results out of reneq fwiw.

I also hate the eqs in the waves audio track

Can't make the digi Air EQ sound good either.  YMMV

Comment: +1 for Oxford! I need to try Q1. Never tried the izotope. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

I use Sonar's built in EQ for almost everything, even though I can't figure out how to automate it.  If I have to automate anything, I use KristalEQ that rolled out with the [Kristal Audio Engine](http://www.kreatives.org/kristal/) because it's the first EQ I learned how to play with, so I trust it, even though it's about as feature-rich as my old Walkman.

Comment: Are you using Pro Tools as well?

Comment: Nope.  Not that I wouldn't like to try it, but I simply don't have it, or anything compatible with M-powered.  So, it's Sonar and Live for me, right now.

Answer (score 1):

I use RenEQ and Q10 for almost anything. RenEQ adds a nice coloration, while Q10 has a lot of flexibility giving more bands, closed Qs for notching, and that surgical tools. I also like some of the componentes of McDSP Filterbank... great filters!

Another cool choices are the V-EQ, SSL, API and Pultec emulations from Waves.. expensive, yes, but sound amazing :-)

Comment: Also, isn't there a plug-in program where you can emulate your own EQs? like Hardware EQs you own that you can take an "IR" from?

Comment: I'm with Miguel, RenEQ is my main EQ (sometimes Q10).  I also frequently use the Waves Puigtec, API 550b, and the V-EQ (Neve emulator)

Comment: @Ryan, yes, the Waves Q Clone.  I have never used it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Miguel here..

RenQ it's one of the most responsive EQ plug-ins for me.. I used digidesign plug-ins for a long time and when I tried RenQ for the first time I couldn't believe how sensitive it was. I personally love it.
The Q series have a great quality factor which is ideal for some precise frequency cuts. 
About the Waves emulations.. I like the SSL emulation for certain specific purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the massey 3 band eq .... can anyone recommend a decent cross platform 3 band eq ? The massey stuff is RTAS / TDM only.

Answer (score 1):

I must admit for getting a certain sound, I like the UA Pultec:

[image]
<sub>(source: [fishercreativegroup.com](http://fishercreativegroup.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/pultec.jpg))</sub>

But my workhorses come from iZotope (Alloy and  Ozone).

--jpf

Comment: Jeffery, thanks. Which one do you like on voice?

Comment: I really like the EQ that comes with Izotope too. Jeffrey, how do you do you use it? as a standalone? Is there a way to use the Izotope EQ on an insert?

Answer (score 0):

I love the Flux EpureII Eq. I find it easy to use and love the sound: it can be smooth or surgical, but the sound never disappoint.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What does Chirurgical mean?

Comment: ☺ oh yes, I mean surgical! Often my english is not so english!! 

Comment: Chirurgical = Surgical ;)

Answer (score 0):

Recently I've started using the EQuality from DMG Audio... great general purpose EQ, good price, all formats....
[alt text http://www.dmgaudio.com/imagery/EQuality.png](http://www.dmgaudio.com/imagery/EQuality.png)